# Is my induction on euler's formula sufficient?

Tags: graph-theory

$n-m+l=2$, where n=#vertices, m=#edges, l=#faces. I've been asked to demonstrate an intuitive, inductive proof (whatever the hell that means). Anyway so I've shown it's true for a tree, where necessarily $m \leq n-1$, and also for when $m=n$. Am I done, or do I need to show it also for when $m \geq n+1$?

Comment: You need to show it when $m\geq n$

Comment: You do. Can you reduce a planar graph to a tree, while keeping the Euler coefficient fixed?